# PHP AJAX RSS onload

Tags: php, ajax, rss

I'm  currently using this RSS feed reader from w3schools: [W3schools RSS Reader](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp).

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   function showRSS(str) {
   if (str.length==0) {
   document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
   return;
    }
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
   document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    } 
   xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<form>
<select onchange="showRSS(this.value)">
<option value="">Select an RSS-feed:</option>
<option value="Google">Google News</option>
<option value="NBC">NBC News</option>
</select>
</form>
 <br>
 <div id="rssOutput">RSS-feed will be listed here...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the PHP code:

```
<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//find out which feed was selected
if($q=="Google") {
  $xml=("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss");
} elseif($q=="NBC") {
  $xml=("http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml");
}

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}
?>
```

changes that I tried:

How do I get the Google news option to load automatically when the website opens without having to first select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a much simpler solution, which is to use PHP's simplexml_load_file.
Here is the entire code:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
$title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
$link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
$description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
$pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
$html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
$html .= "$description";
$html .= "<br />$pubDate";
}
echo $html;
?>
```